# error in navicat lite mysql gui : Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, navicat

I am using navicat lite with mysql database.

my database is test

and i have a **table named transactions with schema**:
date, sharename,buyORsell,quantity,finalrate

I am trying to create a new procedure which takes some input and outputs some results, and I would want that when I execute this procedure, this procedure asks for the input parameter from the user and outputs results accordingly.

**My requirement:** given a input (transaction type i.e. 'buy' or 'sell'), it should output all the transactions with that type

I create a function and click on procedure

```
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...
select * from test.transactions where buyORsell = intype;
END
```

In the space below, I see:

```
IN `intype` char
```

But when I run this prcedure and type sell in "enter parameter" pop-up, I get the error:

**Unknown column 'sell' in 'field list'**

Please help..

Comment: buyORsell what a great name for a column....

Comment: Just curious - what is your goal with using a stored procedure in this instance? Seems like a simple SQL query would do the trick alone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by defining char with a length (i.e. `char(254)`) and then wrapping the input string in quotes when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your stored procedure definition and forgot to include the intype as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a Navicat problem. I now use HeidiSQL for functions and that seems to work fine.

With Navicat, the same problem occurs when I have an input parameter - whether or not I use that paramater. Like Martin I can clear out all the code from BEGIN...END but still get the error if I use any char or varchar input parameter.

In fact, using varchar as an input parameter ALWAYS gives a save/compile error with ANY function using Navicat. With Navicat, Varchar in functions seems completely broken.